# Repeater list is not getting updated in OnItemCommand method

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater control. In `OnItemCommand` method of repeater, after doing some operations I am trying to refresh the repeater list so that it could show me the updated list. But somehow repeater list is not updated in method. However when I reload the page then repeater list gets updated with most recent items.

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label ID="Message1" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <div id="ListingAgentsData" class="panel panel-default" style="width: 920px;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptagentList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptagentList_OnItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="results1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <strong>AgentID</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>Email</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>FullName</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>Driver License/Passport</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>Action</strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDayofweek" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AgentID")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCharges" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FullName")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DriverLicense")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ibtn" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AgentID")%>' />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Reject" CommandName="Reject" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AgentID")%>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

`.CS:`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Username"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("../Login/Default.aspx");
    else
    {
        Init();
    }
}

protected void rptagentList_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Approve")
        {
            int agentId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GM gm = new GM();
            if (gm.ApproveListingAgent(agentId))
            {
                Message1.Text = "Listing Agent with ID:"+agentId+" is approved!";
                Init();
            }
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Reject")
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}

private void Init()
{
    ListingAgent Agent = new ListingAgent();
    DataTable dt = Agent.getPendingListingAgents();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rptagentList.DataSource = dt;
        rptagentList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Please help!

Comment: When you click approve, does `Message1.Text` change to what it should? Or does that also not update until reloading the page again?

Comment: `Message1.Text` changes on page as expected. Only list is not getting updated! It updates only when I refresh/reload the page.

Comment: So when you stick a breakpoint on the `Message1.Text =` line, your debugger hits it? As in, `gm.ApproveListingAgent(agentId)` is returning true properly?

Comment: That's correct! There is nothing wrong with `ApproveListingAgent` method. Infact when I add `Response.Redirect("Same ASPX page")` the page reloads and list gets updated with correct items. But I want to update list without page reload! Is it possible?

Comment: Well it should be possible. I don't see why not. When you place a breakpoint in your `Init()` method, does `dt` contain the data you expect?